# JavaScript onClick event in golang

Tags: html, go

In an attempt to automate some web/browser tasks with golang I reached a barrier when if comes comes to click, touch and swipe interaction.

Thanks to the amazing https://github.com/PuerkitoBio/goquery library I am able to parse webpages and I am able to interact with form sheets.

One integral part that is missing to automate pates is simulating mouse clicks that trigger javascript.

How would it be possible to implement this in  golang? Do I need to simulate OS level mouse clicks or do browsers have an API that I can use?

Comment: To help with a question "Do browsers have an API" i think they do and if i'm not mistaking it's [DOM API here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model) read more about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to use something like [Selenium](http://www.seleniumhq.org/)'s [WebDriver](http://www.seleniumhq.org/projects/webdriver/) which has at [least one go client](https://github.com/sourcegraph/go-selenium)

Comment: Thank you for the answer Jack. So dies selenium use Javascript under the hood or some direct interaction with html,css? Thanks

Comment: Depends on what browser you're wanting to control. Ultimately that's an implementation detail that shouldn't matter much to you since it will be abstracted away by the client API. See http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp for more info